# Issues when running npm start

Tags: node.js

I recently faced this problem when trying to run `npm start` while nodemon works just fine.

I tried many things but I keep getting the same error. It started occurring right after I upgraded node.js to 14.15.5.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! path bash
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 start script.        
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Does anybody have the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete package-lock.json and run npm install again?  That's my gut reaction to those types of errors.  I've also had issues with upgrading to node 14, and have downgraded to 12 for most cases.

Comment: Hi  Jason, yes I have tried to remove node_modules folder, as well as the pack-lock.json and run npm install. I also did the same cleaning the npm cache without improvement.